# How safe is it not closing a connection to a sqlite database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I know that this questions has been asked before, but I hold a responsibility for a big amount of very important data and I need to do anything necessary to protect it.

Here's a scenario: my python script that uses the database (using sqlite) runs 24/7, now, what if, for some reason, my machine dies, like lost it's power (unplugged) or somehow shutdowned normally (you never know, a hacker might do this :-P)

Is there a chance my database gets corrupted because of some unfinished transaction that needed to be done by the sqlite? Or should I stay calm because sqlite might catch thesel system shutdown message and do appropriate things to ensure my db don't get corrputed? How about using with blocks? can they handle such scenarios?

Comment: Backups, and often. If you really want to be safe, you should implement a log shipping type of database backup but I doubt SQLite supports that. Postgresql does though.

Comment: thanks @RodneyHawkins but from a scale of 1-100 how often do you think I would get corrupted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a chance my database gets corrupted because of some
>   unfinished transaction that needed to be done by the sqlite?

It is unlikely as a partially written transaction should be rolled back. That's what the jounal or WAL files are for.

I'd suggest having a good read of [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)